# How to fix 'IDE Internal Error Occured' in Android Studio that occurs everytime I select a component?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I get an IDE Internal Error occurred every time I select a component and the entire Android Studio software becomes sluggish. I am not able to edit the attributes of any components. Every time I select a component, the attributes window fixed to the right becomes unresponsive and I get the error. I am running Android Studio 3.4.2

Here is the error report I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: Already
>   disposed: Project (Disposed) Attendyx     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:179)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:678)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:373)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.doWriteAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:392)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ReprocessContentRootDataActivity$runActivity$1.run(ReprocessContentRootDataActivity.kt:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed: Project (Disposed)
>   Attendyx  at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.lambda$throwAlreadyDisposed$1(ComponentManagerImpl.java:245)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.lambda$run$1(ReadAction.java:53)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:973)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:57)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.run(ReadAction.java:53)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.throwAlreadyDisposed(ComponentManagerImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getPicoContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:236)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.roots.ProjectRootManager.getInstance(ProjectRootManager.java:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.roots.ex.ProjectRootManagerEx.getInstanceEx(ProjectRootManagerEx.java:26)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.commit(AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.java:432)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ReprocessContentRootDataActivity$runActivity$1$5.run(ReprocessContentRootDataActivity.kt:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1057)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.lambda$doWriteAction$7(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:392)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:156)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:755)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:704)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:391)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: An "Internal Error" indicates a bug in the IDE itself. You can't fix it, only the developers of the IDE can. Check whether the developers have released a newer, fixed, version of the IDE.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it